# Using FTC to calculate $\int_a^b \frac{1}{z} dz$

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

> Use the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus (FTC) to calculate $\int_a^b \frac{1}{z} dz$ for any pair of non-zero complex numbers $a,b$ such that the line segment from $a$ to $b$ does not contain $0$. Then, use your answer to find an example of a triangle $\Delta$ with vertices $a,b,c$ such that $\int_a^c \frac{1}{z} dz - \int_a^b \frac{1}{z} dz \neq \int_b^c \frac{1}{z} dz$.

Here's what I have so far: By FTC, we know that $\int_{\gamma} f(z)dz = g(\gamma(b))-g(\gamma(a))$. We also know that $f(z)=\frac{1}{z}$ has an antiderivative given by $\log(z)$ away from the cut line.

I am thus tempted to conclude that $\int_a^b \frac{1}{z} dz = \log(b) - \log(a)$, but this wouldn't seem to be conducive to finding an example for the second part of the problem.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that the "cut line" for the $\log$ function has to change depending on where $a$ and $b$ are.  The cut line cannot intersect the line segment from $a$ to $b$, since the antiderivative has to be defined on the entire curve of integration.

Given particular points $a$ and $b$, you can find a cut line that works, but there is not a single cut line that works for all $a$ and $b$.  Equivalently, there is no single function "$\log$" that works for all $a$ and $b$.

This should help you find a counterexample for the second part of the problem.

Comment: So when I choose a particular set of points $a$ and $b$, I can always find a branch such that $\log(z)$ is analytic, and thus can use FTC to conclude that $\int_a^b \frac{1}{z} dz = \log(b)-\log(a)$ for $a,b \neq 0$ which don't intersect the cut line. Then, for a counterexample, suppose I choose a triangle with vertices $a=i, b= -1+i, c=-1-i$, and define $\log(z)$ using the principal branch. Since the line segment from $a$ to $b$ doesn't cross the cut line, $\int_a^b \frac{1}{z} dz = \log(-1+i) - \log(i)$. Is this correct? Then how would I evaluate the other two line segments?

Comment: For this triangle, it would be more convenient to choose the cut line as the *positive* real line (rather than using the principal branch), since the positive real line does not intersect any of the sides of the triangle.  This gives a single branch of $\log$ that works for all 3 sides of the triangle, so it won't be a counterexample for the second part of the problem.

Comment: Sorry, I'm still a bit confused. Isn't the point to choose a cut line that does intersect some of the line segments of the triangle so that the $\log$ function is undefined? Otherwise, if none of the segments intersected the cut line, wouldn't we be able to use FTC for all three segments and conclude that $\int_a^c \frac{1}{z} dz - \int_a^b \frac{1}{z} dz = \int_b^c \frac{1}{z} dz$, contrary to what we want?

Comment: The FTC works for *any* branch of the log function that doesn't intersect the curve of integration.  The value of the integral doesn't depend on the choice of cut line as long as it doesn't intersect the curve of integration.  So if there exists a cut line that intersects none of the sides of the triangle, then you get $\int_a^b + \int_b^c = \int_a^c$.  The fact that some other cut line would intersect the triangle doesn't matter.  You have to find a triangle where *every* cut line intersects at least one of the sides.

Comment: Okay, that makes sense. Let's say I choose the triangle with vertices $a=i, b= -1-i, c= 1-i$. The interior of this triangle contains the origin, so then every cut line must intersect at least one of the sides. Would this be a viable counterexample?

Comment: Yes, that is correct.